# Using LogicApp to make post in Teams with link to open pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-logic-apps

I know it's possible to create Logic App in Azure to send message in Teams after completing pipeline. I don't know how can I add hash with completed pipeline as clickable link to open.
I couldn't find any information how can I do this.
I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps Pipelines already have [official support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops) to integrate into Microsoft Teams that you could use directly, even without a Logic App.

But if you still need to use a Logic App, then what you could do is use the [Invoke a REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task to call your Logic App, and then [send an Adaptive Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#post-adaptive-card-in-a-chat-or-channel) which you can [design](https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer/) to have a button which links to the pipline.